# Arch Linux can't auto mount removable storage device

Tags: arch-linux, automount, hal

I have installed Arch Linux with Gnome but it can not mount removable storage, usb sticks etc. gnome-disk-utility package installed but i can not find automount package.

I think i need configure HAL or install other package for this solution.

How can i enable auto mount?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question title: It can, you just haven't told it to. As always, the [Arch wiki](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Auto_mounting_USB_devices) has the answer.

Also, if you're using gnome, then as far as I know, all you need to do is add your user to the `storage` group.

Comment: i'm a member of storage group. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

it solved.

Create /etc/hal/fdi/policy/preferences.fdi file and write:

```
<merge key="volume.ignore" type="bool">false</merge>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest GNOME, Nautilus handles automounting. HAL is obsolete, and the `storage` group is only needed if you do not have ConsoleKit installed.